# Should I ask multiple variations of my question in one post?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask about the safest place to camp on a mountain, but I'd like answers for different kinds of mountains-- hilly kinds (like found in some parts of New Mexico), rocky kinds (like in high Sierras of California), alpine kinds (completely covered with trees), etc...

Should this be individual questions or a multi-faceted question? I guess I assumed the question would have different answers for different types, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the overall SE Meta site [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

> Split them and ask multiple questions.
>
> That way it's easy to select a correct answer. If you ask several
>   questions in one question you risk having answers that are both
>   correct and wrong at the same time.